# a problem on arithmetic progression,it is a very confusing sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

In an arithmetic progression,the sum of five terms is equal to 1\4 of the next five terms,prove that the 20th term is -112?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessarily true.  If you write your progression as $T(n)=a+nd$.  We have $$\sum_{i=0}^4T(i)=\frac 14\sum_{i=5}^9T(i)\\5a+10d=\frac14 (5a+35d)\\d=-3a$$  This does not let us show that $a+19d=-112$  For example, we could have $a=1, d=-3$.  The sum of the first five terms is $-25$, the sum of the next five is $-100$, and the twentieth term is $-56$.  Is there more information available?  We need to show that (for example) $a=2$ and we are home.

Comment: Note that in this case the "first" term is $n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say **which** five terms, but I suppose it's the first five.
Well, if the $n$th term is $a + n b$, how can you express the sum of the first five and the sum of the next five in terms of $a$ and $b$?